# "org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.DataStoreException: Could not add record" exception when installing a package Adobe AEM

Tags: aem, jcr

Next error during package installation:

```
    25.09.2018 14:19:29.154 *ERROR* [qtp2146607925-109] org.apache.jackrabbit.vault.packaging.impl.ZipVaultPackage Error during install.
    javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Inaccessible value
            at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.value.ErrorValue.createException(ErrorValue.java:94)
 ...
            at org.apache.jackrabbit.vault.fs.impl.io.FileArtifactHandler.importNtResource(FileArtifactHandler.java:359)
            ... 58 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.DataStoreException: Could not add record
            at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore.addRecord(FileDataStore.java:230)
            at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.datastore.DataStoreBlobStore.addRecord(DataStoreBlobStore.java:538)
            at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.datastore.DataStoreBlobStore.writeStream(DataStoreBlobStore.java:637)
            at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.datastore.DataStoreBlobStore.writeBlob(DataStoreBlobStore.java:224)
            ... 70 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can not rename /opt/aem/data-store/tmp3776489360147109357.tmp to /opt/aem/data-store/b6/ea/7d/b6ea7d9744c3fe943e9166246f559558278b287cc532cef6d97a9ad4036bdb5c (media read only?)
            at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore.addRecord(FileDataStore.java:205)
            ... 73 common frames omitted
```

Cannot install the package because of the exception. Adobe AEM 6.3

Comment: Seems pretty clear that whatever is doing this does not have write access to that location. But this doesn't seem on-topic for SO.

Comment: right. Just wanted to post the stack trace here to find it in future in case of the same error or help someone else to resolve the issue quickly

Answer (score 5):

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can not rename /opt/aem/data-store/tmp3776489360147109357.tmp to /opt/aem/data-store/b6/ea/7d/b6ea7d9744c3fe943e9166246f559558278b287cc532cef6d97a9ad4036bdb5c (media read only?)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore.addRecord(FileDataStore.java:205)
        ... 73 common frames omitted
```

Root cause of the issue was lack of permissions for the linux user that was using to run AEM. Somehow only root user had permissions for the "/opt/aem/data-store/b6/ea" folder.

```
$ ls -ld ea
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 16 Sep 25 14:05 ea
```

It was fixed after I granted permissions for the folder to the "aem" linux user with the command:

```
sudo chown -R aem:users /opt/aem/data-store
```

Comment: I'd speculate that it was started as root at some point previously.